# Get entity inside other entity without relation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have an `User` entity, and the `User` entity has relation to `UserLevel` entity which is a simple `ManyToOne` (user table has `level_id` field).

`User` can have the next level, it depends on the `priority` field of the `UserLevel` entity and it also depends on other `User` relation `Roles` (some `levels` are available only for certain `roles`).

Can I somehow get the next user level through `User` entity, without touching other classes?

Here's the SQL I use for getting the next level:

```sql
SELECT id 
FROM user_level 
WHERE priority > :priority AND company_roles && ARRAY[$roleIds]::BIGINT[] 
ORDER BY priority 
LIMIT 1
```

What I do now is:

```php
$em->getRepository('UserLevel')->findNextUserLevel(User $user);
```

What I'd like to do is:

```php
$user->getNextLevel();
```

Is this possible? Or am I maybe doing it the wrong way?

Comment: This is known as an active record approach.  It is widely used but Doctrine does not directly support it.  The idea in Doctrine 2 would be to load in the levels when you load in the user.  Having said that, search around a bit for how to globally access the container which in turn will give you access to the repository from inside your entity.

Comment: I am sure this is not okey to get repository of entity inside the entity, isn't it ?

Comment: The active record folks (of which there are many) would say it is fine.  The data mappers (D2's approach) not so much.  One of Symfonys popular cousins, Laravel, uses the active record approach.  It is your choice.

Comment: To be honest with you, I'm sick and tired of active record (since I was using Yii a lot).

Comment: In that cases the answer is simple:  No.  As described, $user->getNextLevel requires access to the database which cannot be done from inside the entity without giving the entity access to the database.  Explore Doctrine 2's query functionality and go with it.  I see no reason why the level cannot be loaded when you load the user.